# django heroku 0010_alter_group_name_max_length.py missing in 'auth' app

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to make users login with a "email - password" combo instead of "username - password" on my django website hosted on heroku

I have used [this tutorial](https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username) which works well on my computer (migrations included) but when i try to migrate my online installation i get an error saying that :

`"django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration account.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0010_alter_group_name_max_length')"`

The migration file looks like that:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0010_alter_group_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', account.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

My `ÌNSTALLED_APPS` from `settings.py` :

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #Base apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    #3rd party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    #local apps
    'account',
    'company',
    'api',
]
```

As you can see, there's this line in my file which makes my migration require a migration in a `auth` folder (which i think is the auth folder of the django framework

```
('auth','0010_alter_group_name_max_length'),
```

On the web i found that it is an existing file in the [django project git](http://%20https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0010_alter_group_name_max_length.py)

Maybe it is caused by the `django-heroku` pip package that i had to install to make this project compatible with heroku servers?

I have no clue about how to make this project work. I tried removing the dependencie in the migration file but i get another error in this case:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 604, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'auth.Group' cannot be resolved
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and show us the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of your `settings.py`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, here it is edited

Comment: That migration looks like it will be included with Django 2.2, which isn't out yet (though it's [available in 2.2a1, 2.2b1, and 2.2rc1](https://github.com/django/django/commit/e81955401885a93a459bcc130642b6ea5bf4ba4d)). Are you using a Django 2.2. prerelease on your local machine? Why isn't that reflected in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: If you [edit] your question again and add your dependency file (`requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`) we can look at it with you.

Comment: Seems like i have Django==2.2.dev20190101154022

Comment: I think i have the wrong version of Django on Heroku, i have not written the versions in my requirements.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a prerelease of Django installed locally, but the stable version on Heroku.

It's a really good idea to lock your dependencies down to ensure that you're running the exact same versions everywhere. This idea is baked into specifications and tools like [Pipfile](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile#the-concept), [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [pip-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/), as well as popular dependency managers for other languages.

Try running

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This should add tight versions to your dependencies, and also list indirect dependencies as well. Commit that change and push to Heroku.

You might want to consider looking into the tools I linked above. Both Pipenv and pip-tools work fine with Heroku, the first via native support and the second by using `requirements.txt` as its lock file.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris noticed in the comments, i had a different version of Django in local and online, the local version of Django was Django==2.2.dev20190101154022 and online version was Django==2.1.7 which had a different migration file (`0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length` in Django 2.1.7 and `0010_alter_group_name_max_length` in 2.2.dev20190101154022)

Comment: Yes, changing that dependency in your migration will help. But it's still important to define your dependencies precisely. Please make sure to take a look at my answer. Whether you choose to upgrade your production install to a 2.2 prerelease or to do something else, this is a good practice to follow.